# Tune IIS 6 for high-cpu, high-RAM server

Tags: iis-6, memory

Are there any suggested tuning options for a web server running on a multi-core (16) server with 16GB RAM? It is an old DB server that was transitioned to a load balanced web server farm however with all that gear I would expect it to be running faster than it is. Running Server 2003 R2 - 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

IIS is fairly scalable. The only thing I can think of is to set the number of worker processes in your application pools to total at least the number of cores you have, and increase the maximum memory for each application pool.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much what I thought re: IIS being scalable. And I know when to change the worker processes however where can I increase the max mem per app? Under the recycling tab, max used?